# There is no URL template for action 'actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION' with zero required parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, voice-recognition, voice, app-actions

This is my actions.xml action, regarding the GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION

```
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION">
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://www.xelion.com/stats{?exerciseType}">
        <parameter-mapping
            entityMatchRequired="true"
            intentParameter="exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name"
            required="true"
            urlParameter="exerciseType" />
    </fulfillment>
    <parameter name="exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet" />
    </parameter>
</action>
```

This is my ExerciseEntitySet:

```
  <entity-set entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet">

    <!-- For each entity you can specify the name, alternate names and the identifier -->
    <!-- The identifier is the value that will be added to the action uri. -->
    <!-- For our sample we map the supported entities with the class FitActivity.Type  -->

    <entity
        name="running"
        identifier="RUNNING" />
    <entity
        name="walking"
        identifier="WALKING" />
    <entity
        name="cycling"
        identifier="CYCLING" />
</entity-set>
```

As you can see the parameter-mapping strictly says REQUIRED and entityMatchRequired="true"
But when I run the App Actions Test Tools and "Update Preview" it says:

```
 13:09  App Actions Test Tool v3.0.0
        Preview Creation Error
        Status Code: 400
        Message: Precondition check failed.
        - There is no URL template for action 'actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION' with zero required parameters.
```

I literally copied this from THEIR Sample:
https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/devrel/android/fitactions

Why doesn't it compile. Why doesn't it recognise my parameters?

Comment: I had a similar issue with `GET_FOOD_OBSERVATION`, and it looks like adding another `<fulfillment>` with no parameters AFTER my parameterized `<fulfillment>` resolved my issue. So for instance, maybe try adding `<fulfillment urlTemplate="https://www.xelion.com/stats">` after your closing `</fulfillment>` node. I'm thinking it may be required as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now. The test tool includes a clarification on what's needed here. In this case you need a fallback fulfillment, in case the first fulfillment isn't triggered, the fallback will act as a catch all.

Comment: Hm I get the error `Missing fulfillment for action 'my.own.ACTION' with zero required parameters. Add a fallback fulfillment with no required parameters.` this seems to be the same issue. What can I do?

Comment: This sample should help clarify how to add a [fallback fulfillment](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/health-and-fitness/get-exercise-observation#handle-intent-parameters-as-url-parameters:~:text=%3C!%2D%2D%20Provide%20a%20fallback%20fulfillment%20with%20no%20required%20parameters.%20For%20example%2C%20to%20your%20app%20search%20or%20router%20deeplink%20%2D%2D%3E,%20%3Cfulfillment%20urlTemplate%3D%22myapp%3A%2F%2Fdeeplink%22%20%2F%3E,-%3C%2Faction%3E).